# Do I need to run "create-react-app" to create a react project every time?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, module, npx

Do I need to run `npx create-react-app` everytime to start a new project.

This command takes **alot of time** to complete on my machine, and the `node_modules` directory is relatively large *(270mb)*. Do I need to run it for every project?

I need your help on this.
I am just starting out in react and node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`create-react-app` is a fast way of downloading the GitHub repository. There are plenty of other boilerplates you can download but this one is the most popular.

If you are concerned with the size of it, you do not need to run `create-react-app` every time. You can make a react project yourself quite easily and by doing so you have much more control and understanding of your project. I recommend looking up how to set up a react project from scratch using the MERN stack.

node_modules will always be quite large but by using a bundler like webpack or parcel.js, you don't have to worry about distributing the entire directory.